# Use VB.NET to download a file from a server protected with .htaccess?

Tags: .net, vb.net, download

on my website i have password protected directory that contains a file with some information in it.

Now ih ave application in vb2010 .net where it will download that string from tha file.

But it gives me an error , that i have not the permission.

It's protected with just the .httaccess files.

How to download tha string even if it's in a password protected directory.

I use the system.net webclient to download the string.

Comment: You'll need to set the network credentials (.htaccess uses standard HTTP Auth). Show the code for what has already been tried.

Comment: i've only used the webclient1.downloadstring(string) code so far

Comment: Do you know the correct credentials to access the file?  You can't get the file in the password protected directory unless you do.

Comment: yes i know my username and password, i've used the networkcredentials with the webclient but still no luck. I also need to fill in a domain is this only the toplevel domain or the domain where the file is located ?